# How to put Strings in an array

Tags: java, android

I am taking prices from the database as

```
 if (dataSnapshot.child("Price").getValue() != null) {
    Price = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Price").getValue().toString());
    Log.d("Reservation", "c" + Price);
 }
```

The values of prices increase according to the services. 
How can I add these Price values in an array as `{20, 30 , 50}`

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Don't. add them to a list. An array requires you to know the number of elements to add before creating it, that means you would have to make a SELECT COUNT before your actual select statement

Comment: If you get data in the form of JSON then search about JSON Beautifier

Comment: @Stultuske how i can add them to a list

Comment: @FerruxNebiyev no it is in the form of String

Comment: First add them to ArrayList, using add(your_str) method then after you get everything you can print them using System.out.println("ArrayList: " + arrayList);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have understood that you are doing the above code logic inside a for loop or some event call. In this case you should make a list and keep each price inside that list

Declare `ArrayList` some where out of loop or method

```
ArrayList<String> priceList = new ArrayList();

if (dataSnapshot.child("Price").getValue() != null) {
    priceList.add(dataSnapshot.child("Price").getValue().toString());
 }
```

Now you have values in `priceList` like {20,10,30} etc and can use it anywhere.

Comment: Good implementation

Comment: its giving as {20}{30} separately

Comment: If you Log it `Log.e("Reservation", "Array Values:" + priceList);`. It will give you values `[20, 10, 30]` not what you said.

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not know the number of elements from Price in your database, an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is the best solution, which is a

> Resizable-array implementation of the List interface.

Create an `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<String> yourList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and add each Price using a loop

```
//while there is still elements from Price in database
      if (dataSnapshot.child("Price").getValue() != null) {
           Price = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Price").getValue().toString());
           yourList.add(Price);
           ...
```

Comment: its not giving the values as {12, 20, 30} instead it is giving as {20} {10} separately

Comment: Maybe you should try declaring and initialising the `ArrayList` outside any loop, like a global variable.